# How to modify array inside function which doesn't take this array as parameter

Tags: c++, reference, dynamic-arrays

What I need is to modify **pTab** array inside **modifyAA(int a)** function.
How can I achieve this?

Example Code:

```
int modifyAA(int a); 

int main()
{
  *pTab=new int[10]; int a=13;

  for(int i=0;i<=9;i++)
      pTab[i]=88;                      

  modifyAA(a);      
  //I'd like to have pTab to be modified after function invoke
return 0;
}

modifyAA(int a){

  for(int i=0;i<=9;i++)
     pTab[i]=pTab[i]+1; 

a=a+pTab[0];  
return a;                  
};
```

Is it possible to modify array when function doesn't take it as parameter ?

Comment: Why exactly do you not want to pass it as a parameter?

Comment: Why ever would you want to do that? That is a horrible practice that makes your code harder to understand.

Comment: It's not that i want to do, it's something that i have to do :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a global variable for the pointer to the first element of the  dynamic array:

```
int * pTab;

int printAA(int a)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0 i != 10; ++i)
    {
        ++pTab[i];
    }
    return a + pTab[0];
}

int main()
{
    pTab = new int[10];

    // populate

    printAA(13);
}
```

Comment: Global variables are Evil™ :)

Comment: That was correct answer. Even if the global variables are evil, in my case that made the job done.

Answer (score 2):

You could use global variables.  This could be practical especially if several functions like `printAA()` would need to call it.

However there is a risk of using *pTab before it's allocated.  And also, you remember now the size, but if later you'd change the size to 10,  you would have to find back all the places where you've hardcoded the 10 or the 9.

If the goal of not passing the parameter is mainly because you call the function a lot of times you could opt for a `std::bind`,  creating a kind of dynamic function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

int printDynArr(int* dynarr, size_t sz, int a)  // proper function with all parameters 
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sz; i++)
        dynarr[i]++;            // It's a pointer, so you modify the data where it is stored 
    a += dynarr[0];
    return a;
};

int main()
{
    int *pTab = new int[10]; int a = 13;    //declaring and alocating - dynamic array
    auto printAA = std::bind<int>(printDynArr, pTab, 10, std::placeholders::_1);   // dynamic function shortcut with predefind parameters

    ...    
    printAA(a);           //using function without giving pTab as argument.                  

    std::cin.get(); 
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you were to do this "The C++ way", you could use a `vector` and iterators from stdlib, like so:

```
#include <vector>

typedef std::vector<int> PTab;   // Defines a type for your pTab, it's a vector of integers

int printAA(PTab::iterator from, PTab::iterator until, int a);    //declaring some func

int main()
{
    PTab pTab(10, 88);      // Initializes pTab vector to 10 elements all containing 88

    int a = 0;
    printAA(pTab.begin(), pTab.begin() + 10, a);

    return 0;
}

int printAA(PTab::iterator from, PTab::iterator until, int a)
{
    for (PTab::iterator i = from; i != until; ++i)
    {
        *i++;      // Increments current element by 1
    }

    a += *from;  // Adds the value of the from element to a
    return a;
};
```

This way you don't pass the vector itself to the function, instead, you only pass a range of iterators, which gives the function a possibility to access the contents of the vector, but not to modify the vector object itself (ie. clear it, resize it, etc.).

Comment: _"The C++ way"_ ... is _idiomatically_ the word you're looking for?